# Retain old versions of AWS service catalog products

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-service-catalog

I am facing issues with retaining the old versions of products in AWS servicecatalog, whenever i am updating the stack it removes the old version and create a new one, i wanted to retain latest 3 versions of products when updating the stack to latest  version

Expecting the retain latest 3 versions of product via cloudformation template

Answer (score 0):

To retain the older version you should use create_provisioning_artifact servicecatalog from boto3. Check this documentation.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/servicecatalog/client/create_provisioning_artifact.html

This will always create a new provisioning artifact version, retaining the older one.

Hope this helps!